# Secondary menu gets cut off

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I've been trying to find out what I have done wrong with my website.  The header element seems to be fixed somewhere, so when I generate a secondary menu, it gets cut off before the second link.  In addition, if the site is shrunk in width  to the point where the logo reduces in width, the site title also starts to be truncated from the bottom.

I'd hoped this would be an easy CSS fix, but I am genuinely at a loss as to where I need to look.

Site link is here, let me know if I need to post anything more.

https://aegisphotography.uk/

I have tried setting the z-index for the menu item, but I suspect the issue is a wider one that that because of how the site title is also affected.

EDIT:  I think the offending div is contained in this section of the HMTL.  Unfortunately because it's WordPress it's not immediately apparently which div I need to adjust to sort out the issue.  Looking at the Inspect feature in Chrome, I suspect that it's the "div class=elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no", but I can't work out how to stop the boundary of the div element from shearing off the content that crosses it.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-dark-grayscale"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 0.49803921568627" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.49803921568627" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 0.49803921568627" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-grayscale"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-purple-yellow"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.54901960784314 0.98823529411765" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.71764705882353 0.25490196078431" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-blue-red"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.27843137254902" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.5921568627451 0.27843137254902" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-midnight"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 0" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.64705882352941" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-magenta-yellow"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.78039215686275 1" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.94901960784314" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.35294117647059 0.47058823529412" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-purple-green"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.65098039215686 0.40392156862745" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 1" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.44705882352941 0.4" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 0 0" width="0" height="0" focusable="false" role="none" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;" ><defs><filter id="wp-duotone-blue-orange"><feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix" values=" .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 .299 .587 .114 0 0 " /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" ><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.098039215686275 1" /><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0.66274509803922" /><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.84705882352941 0.41960784313725" /><feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 1" /></feComponentTransfer><feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in" /></filter></defs></svg>
<a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to content</a>

        <div data-elementor-type="header" data-elementor-id="625" class="elementor elementor-625 elementor-location-header">
                                <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-11ed783d elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-min-height elementor-section-stretched elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-items-middle" data-id="11ed783d" data-element_type="section" data-settings="{&quot;stretch_section&quot;:&quot;section-stretched&quot;}">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-5b52dca5" data-id="5b52dca5" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-59c101a elementor-section-full_width elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="59c101a" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-9f01871" data-id="9f01871" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-ff4ec88 elementor-widget__width-initial elementor-widget elementor-widget-theme-site-logo elementor-widget-image" data-id="ff4ec88" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="theme-site-logo.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <style>/*! elementor - v3.12.2 - 23-04-2023 */
.elementor-widget-image{text-align:center}.elementor-widget-image a{display:inline-block}.elementor-widget-image a img[src$=".svg"]{width:48px}.elementor-widget-image img{vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block}</style>                              <a href="https://aegisphotography.uk">
            <img width="100" height="100" src="https://aegisphotography.uk/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Logo-tiny.png" class="attachment-full size-full wp-image-505" alt="" loading="lazy" />                </a>
                                            </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-a377568" data-id="a377568" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-fe41192 elementor-widget elementor-widget-theme-site-title elementor-widget-heading" data-id="fe41192" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="theme-site-title.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <style>/*! elementor - v3.12.2 - 23-04-2023 */
.elementor-heading-title{padding:0;margin:0;line-height:1}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title[class*=elementor-size-]>a{color:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-small{font-size:15px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-medium{font-size:19px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-large{font-size:29px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-xl{font-size:39px}.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-xxl{font-size:59px}</style><h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="https://aegisphotography.uk">Aegis Photography</a></h2>       </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-76b2628" data-id="76b2628" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-34ac8ec elementor-widget elementor-widget-shortcode" data-id="34ac8ec" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="shortcode.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-shortcode"><div id="mega-menu-wrap-menu-1" class="mega-menu-wrap"><div class="mega-menu-toggle"><div class="mega-toggle-blocks-left"></div><div class="mega-toggle-blocks-center"></div><div class="mega-toggle-blocks-right"><div class='mega-toggle-block mega-menu-toggle-animated-block mega-toggle-block-0' id='mega-toggle-block-0'><button aria-label="Toggle Menu" class="mega-toggle-animated mega-toggle-animated-slider" type="button" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="mega-toggle-animated-box">
                    <span class="mega-toggle-animated-inner"></span>
                  </span>
                </button></div></div></div><ul id="mega-menu-menu-1" class="mega-menu max-mega-menu mega-menu-horizontal mega-no-js" data-event="hover_intent" data-effect="fade_up" data-effect-speed="200" data-effect-mobile="disabled" data-effect-speed-mobile="0" data-mobile-force-width="body" data-second-click="go" data-document-click="collapse" data-vertical-behaviour="standard" data-breakpoint="768" data-unbind="true" data-mobile-state="collapse_all" data-hover-intent-timeout="300" data-hover-intent-interval="100"><li class='mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-menu-item-home mega-current-menu-item mega-page_item mega-page-item-13 mega-current_page_item mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-45' id='mega-menu-item-45'><a class="mega-menu-link" href="https://aegisphotography.uk/" aria-current="page" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Home</a></li><li class='mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-55' id='mega-menu-item-55'><a class="mega-menu-link" href="https://aegisphotography.uk/services/" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Web Design</a></li><li class='mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-169' id='mega-menu-item-169'><a class="mega-menu-link" href="https://aegisphotography.uk/photography/" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Photography</a></li><li class='mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-607' id='mega-menu-item-607'><a class="mega-menu-link" href="https://aegisphotography.uk/shop/" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">My Shop</a></li><li class='mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-46' id='mega-menu-item-46'><a class="mega-menu-link" href="https://aegisphotography.uk/get-in-touch/" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Get In Touch</a></li><li class='mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-menu-item-has-children mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-has-icon mega-icon-left mega-menu-item-1090' id='mega-menu-item-1090'><a class="dashicons-arrow-down mega-menu-link" href="https://aegisphotography.uk/register/" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Login<span class="mega-indicator"></span></a>
<ul class="mega-sub-menu">
<li class='mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-menu-item-1227' id='mega-menu-item-1227'><a class="mega-menu-link" href="https://aegisphotography.uk/register/" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Login/Register</a></li><li class='mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-custom mega-menu-item-object-custom mega-menu-item-1237' id='mega-menu-item-1237'><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://test.com" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Test</a></li></ul>
</li></ul></div></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-3e60f14 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="3e60f14" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-b184bbf" data-id="b184bbf" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: This question needs a little more information. Could you add a screenshot where do see the issue? When I checked the website I cannot find any issues at a glance

Comment: No worries - appears in the top right corner here, where there should be two menu items, but the second is cut off completely.

https://paste.pics/9a48ce126db7e87f8dae86a67b525592

The title distortion is here in the top left:

https://paste.pics/c8ae2b43ffe26200e0a2256020510f33

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Would love to, but I have no idea where the problem code is hiding.  I can just do a copy/paste of the whole stylesheet if that helps, but I suspect that would be a horrible mess that wouldn't help much at all.

Comment: OK, looks like it's a margin issue.  When I add a margin to .elementor-element-34ac8ec, more of the menu shows up.  However, it pushes the rest of the page content down.

Comment: Think I have now fixed it - it was indeed a margin problem, in that the content was being cut off once it crossed the div border.  By adding a margin, I now have a working flyout menu, though the annoying thing is that this has pushed all my content down the page a bit.  Still, seems to be working now.